# What do the IP addresses(under source column) represent/or mean in Inbound and Outbound rules in AWS security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-security-groups

What do the IP addresses(under source column) represent/or mean in Inbound and Outbound rules in AWS security groups?

[image: Please open the link in a new tab to see an example.]

Answer (score 1):

In your case the IP address in source basically means "from where" the database (I am assuming from port 5432 that it is PostgreSQL database) can be accessed OR from what addresses the "inbound" traffic is allowed. Also in your configuration source address is a set of IPs or subnet.
There are other possible options which you can lookup in official docs [here][1].

Comment: So, what about the outbound IPs addresses under Source column? What would they represent? Also, I quickly grabbed above pic from internet to precisely show the source column and it does not belong to me. I am trying to get an overview of IP addresses in Inbound and Outbound rules in security groups.

Comment: Outbound addresses represent destinations to which the outbound traffic is allowed. A possible use-case is "You can optionally restrict outbound traffic from your database servers. For example, you might want to allow access to the internet for software updates, but restrict all other kinds of traffic" as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html

Comment: And if this answers your question then please mark this answer as accepted (as a good practice on SO :-)))